# Check if string address X is within string address Y, using REST API complex polygon

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I was looking for an API but struggling mightily. My approach was to get complex polygon like in the image below for australia:

[image]

One user will come and input me string addresses of `X` like:

- Sydney, Australia

And another user gives me string address of `Y` like:

- Australia

Is there an API that I can hit, gives me complex polygon for the address? The closest I'm getting is getting bounding box (north, west, south, and east lat/lng) by hitting API - https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=australia&key=MY_KEY_HERE

Once I get the complex polygon, I then will try to test if these complex polygons intersect to answer my question wtih: `Yes, X value of "Sydney, Australia" is within Y value of "Australia"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get polygon for country or city you can use [Geodata API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306801.aspx).

Here is documentation for GeoDataAPIManager that is part v8 of Map Control - Spatial Data Services Module: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712862.aspx , you can see code sample on v8 iSDK: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/sdsloadsingleboundary#overview

Once you have boundaries, you can use [Spatial Math Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712834.aspx), to check for [intersection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt762902.aspx). See this code sample: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Find%20all%20counties%20that%20intersect%20a%20line

Comment: Thank you very much @Szymon!! I will try this out and let you know how it goes!